# How to check for #1 being either `d` or `h` with latex3?

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, expl3, latex3

Is there a command in `expl3` to check if #1 is either `d` or `h` or `min` and only then run a piece of code?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\x_test:n#1{
\bool_if:nTF
{
\str_if_eq_p:nn{#1}{h} ||
\str_if_eq_p:nn{#1}{d} ||
\str_if_eq_p:nn{#1}{min}
}
{#1:yes}
{#1:no}
}
\let\test\x_test:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\test{h}

\test{?}

\test{min}

\test{d}

\test{xxx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution. It works perfectly! It is really hard to find the correct `expl3` functions...

Comment: @mrCarnivore you could also use l3regex or `\str_case:nn`  interface3.pdf should have all the information you need